# How to switch right-hand strip to left side in facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(drv ~ .)
```

Which produces this plot:

[image]

As describe above how can I switch right-hand strip to left side and vice versa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `switch` in `facet_grid` to change the facet strip to left and `scale_y_continuous` to change y-axis to right.

```
library(ggplot2)

p + facet_grid(drv ~ ., switch = "y") + 
   scale_y_continuous(position = "right")
```

[image]